# Are there any beasts with an always-available bonus action?

Tags: dnd-5e, druid, actions, wild-shape

I'm currently playing a level 5 [moon druid](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/druid#CircleoftheMoon) (PHB, p. 69), and I really like the [*call lightning*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/call-lightning) spell. Unfortunately, it requires you to use your action repeatedly.

Now, I'm looking for a beast that I can (preferably at this level already) [Wild Shape](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/druid#WildShape) into, which has a bonus action available. This would allow me to use my action to activate *call lightning* every round, and still do other stuff besides moving.

I'm aware of several beasts that have abilities such as *Pounce*. However, these usually require you to use your action for an attack, which defeats the purpose of this question.

Similarly, I know that I can stay in my regular druid form and cast [*healing word*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/healing-word) with my bonus action, or that I can use a bonus action while Wild Shaped to expend a spell slot for healing. Both are, however, situational, expensive and undesirable (unless you want to get yourself or your companions hurt).

**Are there any beasts that are able to use a bonus action without spending their action in a specific way?**

Comment: @Jihelu "I know that I can **stay in Druid form** and cast healing word".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Cranium Rat has an "always available" bonus action, but I would not recommend it for combat. It is a tiny CR 0 beast from Volo's Guide to Monsters and all it can do with its bonus action is this:

> **Illumination.** As a bonus action, the cranium rat can shed dim light from its brain in a 5-foot radius or extinguish the light.

I believe it is the only beast with an "always available" bonus action at the time of writing.

---

Homebrew and UA aside, the only ways to get an "always available" bonus action for Wildshape are to multiclass into a class that grants you a bonus action (such as the Rogue), or to be one of the few playable races with a bonus action (such as the Goblin)... though of course it is too late for your character to be a different race.

Comment: Nice find! It still boggles my mind that the cranium rat is a beast and not a monstrosity or aberration.

Comment: It boggles my mind they made a creature that uses its brain as a flashlight...

Comment: I'm sure the *cranium rat's* mind is similarly boggled by being used as a flashlight